# Mac syscall error

Tags: macos, assembly, system-calls, inline-assembly

If I write to terminal executing `write` syscall myself on Mac, it succeeds:

```
int main() {
    long SYS_WRITE = 0x2000004;
    long STDOUT = 1;

    long result;
    char* str = "Hello world";

    __asm__ __volatile__ (
        "syscall;\n"
        : "=a" (result)
        : "a" (SYS_WRITE), "D" (STDOUT), "S" (str), "d" (10)
        :
    );

    std::cout << result << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

It prints to console "Hello world" and returns `10` as expected.

However if I try to get on purpose an error, for example, by setting `9999` as file descriptor (which does not exist):

```
int main() {
    long SYS_WRITE = 0x2000004;
    long STDOUT = 1;

    long result;
    char* str = "Hello world";

    __asm__ __volatile__ (
        "syscall;\n"
        : "=a" (result)
        : "a" (SYS_WRITE), "D" (9999), "S" (str), "d" (10)
        :
    );

    std::cout << result << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

It returns `9`, which corresponds to `EBADFD` error, which is OK, but the result is not negative. I would expect the error result to be negative, on Linux it is negative.

On Mac, how do I know that `syscall` returned an error?

Comment: According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47834513/64-bit-syscall-documentation-for-macos-assembly): "A syscall return `errno` an sets the carry flag on error, instead of returning `-errno` in `rax`"

Comment: Almost impresively this question is about two languages and neither of them are C

Comment: Not related to your question but something you should consider. The `syscall` instruction clobbers RCX and R11 which should be added to your clobber list.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Thank you very much!

Comment: @Galen Thanks, it looks like you are right, if you post that as an answer I will accept that.