# Saving Status register (EFLAGS) when calling a function

Tags: assembly, gcc, x86, calling-convention, status-register

As I understand, when I'm calling a function, based on GCC Calling Convention, this is what happens:

Caller saves values of AX, CX and DX registers. Arguments and returning address are pushed on stack. Also, callee must preserve values of SI, DI, BX and BP registers.

But, what about Status register? Who saves it?

Also, is value of returning address which is pushed on stack actually value of Instruction register?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The status register is not preserved across function calls. If there's something important in the status register it needs to be copied elsewhere (generally with SETcc), but the calling convention doesn't *require* the calling function to do this, just as it doesn't require the calling function to save and restore AX et al. if there's nothing important in them.

Comment: But if I have some arithmetic function in a calle function, this can change values of some bits in status register(sign flag for example). When calle is done, shouldn't I somehow restore previous values of changed bits when returning to caller function? Or this kind of situation is what you meant by something impotant, and in this case I need to use SETcc?

Comment: No, that's not part of the calling convention, so caller functions won't assume that you're going to do that.

Comment: @Dusan the status register is so volatile (like 1/3 of instruction set modifying it), that it would be quite cumbersome to preserve its value across calls. Also reviewing the code would be a bit of nightmare, if the coders would exploit that to full extent, using some status after several calls or even inside, it's already tricky enough to read 486-586 era code when out-of-order was done mostly manually and often status is set 2-3 instructions ahead from its usage. Or to remember the extras, like the `inc/dec` does not affect carry flag. Would be very impractical to not treat it as temporary.

Comment: @Dusan: As ped7g says, basically every function would need a slow `pushfd` / `popfd` because all traditional (8086) ALU instructions except NOT and LEA modify some part of FLAGS.  See [What are callee and caller saved registers?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56178078) re: the concept of call-clobbered registers and why some of each (call preserved and clobbered) are a very good thing for a calling-convention.

Answer (score 2):

Answering your second question:

> Also, is value of returning address which is pushed on stack actually value of Instruction register?

You mean the value pushed by `call` instruction? Yes, that's current `rip` (`eip/ip` in 32/16 bit modes) value during `call` internal execution (as `rip` points to next instruction).

And the `ret` instruction will pop whatever value is on top of stack, and set that into `rip`, changing the code-execution flow for next instruction (away from the instruction next after the `ret` to the address/value which was in stack). So the value from stack becomes content of `ip` register, after `ret` is finished. The `ret` is like (non-existent) `pop ip`, but it has its own mnemonics to make it stand out in source better when reading it by human, and also it has completely different opcode, so the HW implementation in the transistors is completely specific to it (which makes sense on modern x86 where the `ret` implementation is using many additional tricks for better performance, but I'm sort of curious why 8086 would not encode it as `pop ip`, like just another register for `pop`, was probably somewhat special in some detail even back then).

Answer (score 2):

> GCC Calling Convention

gcc uses the standard calling convention on whatever platform it's targeting.  It sounds like you're describing the i386 System V calling convention / ABI used on Linux, and/or some Windows calling conventions.  (Some of which pass args differently, but make the same choice of registers that can be clobbered.)

You're using 16-bit register names, but gcc barely supports 16-bit x86.  It basically generates 32-bit code and then assembles it with `.code16gcc` so most instructions have operand-size and/or address-size prefixes.  (Including `call` and `ret` so they push and pop a 4-byte return address, unlike with plain `.code16`.)

> Caller saves values of AX, CX and DX registers

No, the caller does that only if it had any data in them that it wants to preserve across the `call`.  The normal case is that the caller lets those values die.  "caller-saved" vs. "callee-saved" is bad terminology because it implies that all registers *actually* get saved somewhere.

Much easier to understand, IMO, is

- **call-clobbered**: EAX, ECX, EDX, and condition codes (part of EFLAGS), all xmm regs
- **call-preserved**: EBX, ESI, EDI, EBP, ESP.

DF must be 0 at call and return, so string instructions go upwards.  (DF, the Direction Flag, is another bit in EFLAGS.)  The x87 stack must be empty on `call` and `ret`, except for functions which return an FP value (in which case `st0` has the return value, and the rest of the x87 stack is empty).

Call-clobbered means that after a `call`, the caller has to assume the register holds garbage, whether or not the callee actually used the register.  *If* there was anything in that register the caller needed for later, it has to move it somewhere else.  But if not, it's totally fine to let the value die.  e.g. to compile something like `rv = foo(a + b + c)`, the caller would calculate `a+b+c` in a register.  But if it doesn't also need that value after the function call, it doesn't have any need to preserve it.

Call-preserved means the caller can assume the register value hasn't changed, whether the callee simply avoided touching that register, or the callee saved / restored it.  (Or for ESP, it's common for the callee to restore it with an `add esp, 28` or similar, to reverse whatever changes it made with `push` and `sub`.)  It doesn't matter how the callee manages to return with call-preserved registers still holding the caller's values, just that it does.  This is why "callee-saved" is also not the clearest term: it implies the callee explicitly saves them.

> But, what about Status register? Who saves it?

**Nobody saves it, except in very rare cases**.  The caller *could* save it if desired, but usually it's far easier and cheaper to to just redo a compare (`popf` is slow, and the `pushf` to save EFLAGS in the first place isn't free).

Or more often there wasn't any useful data in the condition codes, just integer values in integer registers.  Most instructions write EFLAGS, but most of the time you never read those results.  You usually use `add`, `imul`, and so on for the integer result and ignore the flag result.

Fun fact: [64-bit OS X system calls set CF on error, otherwise they clear CF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47834513/64-bit-syscall-documentation-for-macos-assembly).  No common 32 or 64-bit function-calling conventions return anything in EFLAGS; they're just clobbered.  (For Linux system calls, EFLAGS / RFLAGS is preserved.  It's typical for system calls to not clobber any registers, other than the return value, partly because this avoids leaking kernel information back to user space.)

Comment: Now I recalled something... some DOS/BIOS services sometimes return certain flag (usually CF, not sure if only CF) set to indicate "no_value" or "error" state, to differentiate them from ordinary return values. So in rare cases the flags were used also as part of return information, but I can't recall anything since x86 32 bit age using it too.

Comment: @Ped7g: [OS X 64-bit system leave CF set on error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47834513/64-bit-syscall-documentation-for-macos-assembly), but no standard function-calling conventions return anything in flags.  Of course, in hand-written asm you can use custom calling conventions for private functions, and can (and should) optimize away a setcc/test by returning a condition in flags if you don't inline.

Comment: @Ped7g The DOS version 2+ int 21h interface, some DOS int 2Fh interfaces, and ROM-BIOS int 13h interface all return the Carry Flag, usually as an error indicator. The ROM-BIOS int 16h interface functions 01h, 11h, 21h use the Zero Flag, as do a few DOS int 21h functions [such as function 06h](https://fd.lod.bz/rbil/interrup/dos_kernel/2106_dlff.html)