# How to detect a write error in x86-64 assembly under macos

Tags: macos, assembly, x86-64, nasm, system-calls

My question is about the `write` syscall.

I know that if the `write` was successful, the number of bytes written is stored in `rax`, but what happens if an error occurs? I want to store -1 in `rax` in this case.

How can I detect that the the write failed, because of an invalid file descriptor for example.

Comment: What operating system are you programming for?

Comment: @fuz I forgot to mention it's macos

Comment: I think macos sets CF on error and returns the error code in rax, but I'm not sure enough to write up an answer.

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47834513/64-bit-syscall-documentation-for-macos-assembly) might provide you with a bit more information.

Comment: @fuz You're right, your comment was helpful. Thanks a lot

Comment: raw system calls (not the libc wrapper) will return the `errno` code directly, like `EBADF`.  On Linux, error returns are encoded as negative, and no valid system call will ever return `-EBADF`.  On MacOS with CF as sideband signalling of error / non-error, IDK if it's negated or not.