# Socket opening macOS assembly

Tags: c, macos, assembly, terminal, nasm

I'm trying to create a socket in NASM but nothing happens, while in C everything is OK.

My C code:

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include "personalUtils.h"

int main() {
    int fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    tryElse(fd, "Error creating a socket"); //macro

    pauseHere() //macro
}
```

After running this, I open the terminal and run, `lsof -i -a -p <PID>` and the socket is there, but trying to run the below NASM code and calling lsof again nothing is being listed. What am I doing wrong?

```
%include "utils.asm"

;#################################
;       Usefull constants
;#################################
AF_INET      equ 2   ; family internetwork to UDP, TCP, etc
SOCK_STREAM  equ 1   ; stream socket
NO_FLAGS     equ 0

;#################################
;       Main function call
;#################################
        global      _main
        SECTION     .text

_main:  mov rax, 0x2000097
        mov rdi, AF_INET
        mov rsi, SOCK_STREAM
        mov rdx, NO_FLAGS
        syscall

        pauseHere ; NASM macro
```

Comment: Where did you get `0x2000097`? [This document](https://github.com/radareorg/radare2/blob/master/libr/syscall/d/ios-arm-64.sdb.txt#L72) implies 0x80, 97 decimal...

Comment: @AKX 0x2000000 is needed to mark the system call as being a UNIX system call.  So I think it should be `0x2000080` then.  Check `<sys/syscall.h>` when in doubt.  OP should use  `truss` to check if the system call worked as expected.

Comment: @AKX @fuz I used both `0x2000080` and `0x80` but nothing happens. I do not know how to use truss. I'm using `lsof -i -a -p <PID>` since it works with the C program.

Comment: @fuz According to my `dtruss`, `int fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);` doesn't even make a syscall... or at least one isn't printed.

Comment: @AKX What is the system call number given in `<sys/syscall.h>`?

Comment: @AKX socket func by definition creates a syscall to open the socket.

Comment: ARM64 in the title?  But you're writing x86-64 assembly with NASM.  Hopefully that's a typo for AMD64.

Comment: @fuz `$ grep socket /Applications/Xcode.app/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/syscall.h` says `#define SYS_socket         97`.

Comment: @PeterCordes its right, ARM, not amd. NASM is able to write ARM programs, I've written some tests using syscalls before this, and the socket opening is the only that aint working as expected.

Comment: No, NASM is strictly an x86 assembler (as stated in the into to the manual: https://nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc1.html).  The code in your question is x86-64.  RAX is an x86-64 register, `syscall` is an x86-64 instruction.  The AArch64 equivalents are roughly X0 and `svc`.  Run `file` on the `.o` you get from `nasm -f macho64`, and note that it's an x86-64 object file.

Comment: @PeterCordes apple silicon has rosseta2 [link](https://www.computerworld.com/article/3597949/everything-you-need-to-know-about-rosetta-2-on-apple-silicon-macs.html) and that is why all my previous codes worked well. But I will try pure ARM code. Thank you

Comment: Please note that instead of the 64-bit `mov rax, ...` (and the others) you can use the equivalent 32-bit `mov eax, ...` instruction, and that would set the top 32 bits of rax to 0 (i.e. zero-extend).

Comment: @PeterCordes everything solved. Apple silicon accepts the x86_64 .o files and I was putting the wrong number into rax. It should be 0x2000061

Comment: Yes, I know macOS on Apple silicon can run x86-64 programs via Rosetta 2, but it's still x86-64 assembly not AArch64 aka ARM64.  The bare CPU hardware *can't* run these instructions; Rosetta 2 does binary translation (to AArch64 machine code) and caches the optimized results so it doesn't have to re-translate every run.  Your question title is still wrong, you aren't writing ARM64 assembly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct socket(2) value to load to rax is 0x2000061, which is the same as 0x2000000 + 97, which is the same as 0x2000000 + SYS_socket. It's documented in https://github.com/radareorg/radare2/blob/master/libr/syscall/d/darwin-x86-64.sdb.txt

See [64-bit syscall documentation for MacOS assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47834513/64-bit-syscall-documentation-for-macos-assembly) for write(2) that works.

Comment: Shoutout my dude, tku so much